# Zend Framework application served via ip address

Tags: apache, zend-framework, linode

I am trying to setup my linode account to serve a zend framework web application from the IP address of the server.  Everything works if I serve it from a resolved domain name like www.somesite.com/controller/action, but not from 182.324.34.2/controller/action.  I think this has something to do with how zend framework handles routes?  My question is what is the best way to run the application until a domain name is linked to the servers ip.  Is this something I can handle with a .htaccess or apache config or something that needs to be handled via zend framework.

Edit:
I am not using hostname routes.

my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/core/public
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/core/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

my zend framework config is pretty standard, let me know what parts would help.

Comment: You'll have to show more details. How does it *not work*? Any ZF app I've ever configured happily ran from wherever I installed it. Are you using any [hostname routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname)?

Comment: I get a not found from the server.  However the same application runs fine from any normal domain name, just not an ip address.  What kind of details are you looking for?

Comment: Are there any other virtual host entries? Without a `ServerName` directive, I'm not sure how that's even working from the resolved name. Also, why change from the [standard ZF rewrite rules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.rewrite.html#project-structure.rewrite.apache.htaccess)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on an Ubuntu server, you may need to simply disable the default virtual host:

```
sudo a2dissite default
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```